# Place accent in letters inside equation

Tags: symbols, accents

I was using `\~` to place a "tilde" accent on letters. But when I try to use it while in (inline or displaystyle) math mode, it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `\~` is a text accent, use `\tilde`

Comment: Okay, it worked.

Comment: if asking about an error message (`LaTeX Warning: Command \~ invalid in math mode on input line 5.

! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.`  please always show the full error from the log.  Don't show any pdf generated if you scroll past the error, the PDF is never intended to be usable after an error.